# Opening multiple files using the File name field of the Open File Dialog?

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to find a way to automate this with  Auotohotkey.

In explorer `File Open` and `File Save` dialogs you can paste a path into the `File name:` field, clicking open, the file is either saved or opened into the software.

Some software allow you to open multiple files by selecting multiple files and clicking open after. How do I attempt to do this manually?

I've tried;

```
Item1 := "C:\Users\User1\Bash_Build\AHK_DEV\Save_Load Dialog\File1.Psd"
Item2 := "C:\Users\User1\Bash_Build\AHK_DEV\Save_Load Dialog\File2.Psd"
Item3 := "C:\Users\User1\Bash_Build\AHK_DEV\Save_Load Dialog\File3.Psd"

3::
Control, Editpaste, %Item1% %Item2% %Item3%, Edit1
ControlSend, Edit1, {Enter}
```

Or manually pasting this in the `File name` field;

```
C:\Users\User1\Bash_Build\AHK_DEV\Save_Load Dialog\File1.Psd
C:\Users\User1\Bash_Build\AHK_DEV\Save_Load Dialog\File2.Psd
C:\Users\User1\Bash_Build\AHK_DEV\Save_Load Dialog\File3.Psd
```

and  I get this dialog:
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: @Spyre hey sorry about that, fixed. I am just looking for a general approach that is reliable for AHK